# How to redirect a user from an old link to a new one along with slug. Next.js redirect 301

Tags: typescript, redirect, next.js

I changed the URL on one of my subpages that is already hosted. The old link is already unsupported but it exists in many places instead of changing it I would like to make a redirect from the old link to the new. I found something like Next.js Redirects but I have a problem with the implementation.

The old link looked like this

***http://localhost:3000/product/id***

And the new link looks like this

***http://localhost:3000/product/SLUG-id***

My API retrieves data from only based on ID in getServerSideProps. Previously separating slug from id

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: any) => {
    const slugId = context.params.slugId;
    const id = slugId.split('-').pop();

    const apolloClient = initializeApollo(context);
    const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_PRODUCTS,
        variables: {
            id,
        },
    });
    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
    };
};
```

The new flow of the page transmits slug at the time of switching to the subpage with the product

`` <Link href={`/product/${product.slug}-${productId}`}> ``

The old link has an ID but does not have a slug

When my next config looks like this I get an error

```
module.exports = {
    nextConfig,
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/product/:slug',
                destination: '/product/:slugId',
                permanent: true,
            },
        ];
    },
};
```

When i edit next config i got error

```
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected:
  - The root value has an unexpected property, nextConfig, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, future, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
`destination` has segments not in `source` or `has` (slugId) for route {"source":"/product/:slug","destination":"/product/:slugId","permanent":false}


Error: Invalid redirect found
```

Can I redirect the user from the old link to the new one along with the slug in the link. getServerSideProps understand this link and actually the user gets data from what I see but inside the link is not contained slug. And this is important for my SEO

Perfect flow

The user clicks on the old link after all goes to the indicated page. All data is downloaded correctly and in the link you can see slug-id even though it only needs an id to download the data

Answer (score 1):

The `nextConfig` key needs to be spreaded so that Next.js can get the keys inside `nextConfig`

It would like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...nextConfig,
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/product/:slug',
                destination: '/product/:slugId',
                permanent: true,
            },
        ];
    },
};
```

You could also just add the `async redirects() {...` inside the `nextConfig` object

[Spread docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)